# Repeating an effect on blocks in a world

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

What I am trying to accomplish is so when the server starts/reloads the plugin is going to detect all SKULLS in the world and then set a effect on them that is looping and does not end.

My current code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onChunkLoad(ChunkLoadEvent event){
Chunk chunk = event.getChunk();
if(event.getWorld().getName().equals("world")){
    for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++){
            for(int z = 0; z <16; z++){
        Block block = chunk.getBlock(x, y, z);
        if(block.getType() == Material.SKULL){
             event.getWorld().playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 0);
```

Comment: The loop is probably not ending due to the fact that you're looping in a 16*256*16 (65536) amount of blocks. That is for ONE chunk! Doing that for all the chunks cause massive lag, thus giving the impression that the loop never ends

Comment: Also, did you remember to register your event somewhere in your main thread?

Comment: I did register the event unless I did something wrong. I also did a debugg of it and it worked. Here is the register event code: Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new ChestManager(this), this);

Comment: And how did you test that the loop never ends? make sure to add both these information to the question!

Comment: After thinking a bit clearer I see that I dont actually know If the loop ends.

Comment: Try to check it

Answer (score 2):

Looping over 65536 blocks for each chunk loaded is going to put a lot of stress on your server's processor.

You should try `Chunk#getTileEntities()` and see if the tile entity is instanceof `org.bukkit.block.Skull`

Additionally, you are only spawning the particles once, which is when the chunk loads. The best way to make the effect repeating is to store the skulls that get loaded into an `ArrayList` and use a `BukkitRunnable` to continually loop over all the skulls and create a particle effect.

You can read about how to use a `BukkitRunnable` [here](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitRunnable)

Comment: Should also take a look [at SO's Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bukkit/drafts/105168) for further schedule understandment.